# How to use for loop through pandas dataframe w/ nested if to fill nan values in column based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

Good Morning,

I am trying to loop through my dataframe to fill null values based on a set of criteria. Below is the start of my code.

```
for d in lifall['edate']:
if d.isnull():
    if (dcd>999):
        lifall['edate']="200"+lifall['dcd']
else:
    continue
```

I get the error

> `numpy.float64` object has no attribute `isnull`

There will be more added to the if statements below, however, just getting started I need to figure out how to get `isnull()` working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what is `dcd`? What is input df look like and the expected output

Comment: dcd is another column in the lifall dataframe. I can get the if statement/output to work if I can just get it to recognize only those rows where edate is null. The if statements inside the for loop are knowingly incomplete.

Comment: So are you after `lifall.loc[(lifall['edate'].isnull()) & (lifall['dcd'] > 999), 'edate'] = '200' + lifall['dcd']`

Comment: I supposed I should have asked it as `for d in lifall['edate']:
if d.isnull():
    if xxx
else:
    continue`

Comment: Accidentally hit enter and submitted that too quick. Like I said. There will be many many more criteria in those if statements. Those are currently incomplete. Really I just want to loop through and in any row where it is null, be able to set multiple criteria for building the value of edate.

Comment: well for starters you can get just the null rows `lifall.loc[lifall['edate'].isnull(), some_col_name] = #some_operation`

Comment: So then throw the series of if statements where you have #some_operation?

Comment: You'd have to define what these if statements look like, it will be quicker to set all the rows that meet your condition even with multiple statements but you can't use `if` with arrays

Comment: OK, so edate is a field that follows the format yyyyddd. There are several instances where it is null. I have data from 2008-2015. dcd for 2008-09 is a 4 digit code that is the last digit of year and then ddd. After that it becomes just ddd, but there is an fy column to pull year from when creating edate. The final caveat is that Q1 of an FY is days 275+ from the previous calendar year.

Comment: So to clarify that last line. In my dataset if dcd=280 and FY=2011, where edate is null it should be filled with 2010280. However if dcd =80 and FY=2011, edate should be 2011080